# Error unsupported top level event type "topTouchStart" on react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm doing a project on react-native
Currently this project I have built on android success
But when build on IOS generated error `topTouchStart`.

I am currently running a react-native version: `0.50.4`
May the community help me
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Would need some more information than that. Maybe some code snippet? Or something else. `topTouchStart` error can show up even when you have syntax errors in JS. So provide some code, that would be helpful!

Comment: I have pictures on you. Because I do not know why the error?

Comment: Provide a code sample, as I told, this particular error occurs a lot of times in RN. It even occurs when the bundler isn't working or couldn't send the new bundle in delta correctly. So provide some code sample as to what you're doing. A screenshot isn't helpful here.

Comment: My projects make the company up great. There are a lot of components that make shooting a bit difficult.

Comment: Then you cannot expect help at SO. Apologies for that. But you cannot expect remote debugging with a screenshot!

Comment: Can you suggest me to photograph the relevant part code?